# Blueprint 2.0 unmet peer dependency "react-addons-css-transition-group@^15.0.1 || ^0.14"

Tags: blueprintjs

I get the following errors trying to install blueprintjs. What to do? I've installed react-addons-css-transition-group.

```
warning " > @blueprintjs/core@1.35.3" has unmet peer dependency "react-addons-css-transition-group@^15.0.1 || ^0.14".
warning "@blueprintjs/core > pure-render-decorator@1.2.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^15.0.0 || ^0.14.0".
```

Comment: looking at the error message, have you installed the _correct_ versions of react-addons-css-transition-group and react?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `yarn`, it seems these warnings never go away, despite having correctly installed the dependencies. So if your app works then go ahead and ignore these warnings.